# Limit of monotone decreasing function on generalised inverse.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, asymptotics

Consider a right-continuous, monotone decreasing, non-negative function $\bar F(x)$ (its the tail of a probability distribution, but that doesn't matter). Now let
\begin{equation}
I_{n}=\{x : \bar F(x)\leq n^{-1}\}
\end{equation}
and define $\bar F^{-1}(n^{-1})=\inf \,I_{n}$. I want to prove 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n \bar F(\bar F^{-1}(n^{-1}))=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n \bar F(\inf\,I_{n})=1.
\end{equation}
By right continuity of $\bar F(x)$, I think
\begin{equation}
n \bar F(\bar F^{-1}(n^{-1})) \leq 1 
\end{equation}
for all $n$, but I'm struggling to see how I can get an asymptotic bound from below. Any hints appreciated.

Edit: An additional piece of information that might be useful is that $\sup\{x:\bar F(x)>0\}=\infty$